# Consecutive identical integer members of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Can you help me to find and count sub-sequences of consecutive, identical integer members of a long list (at least 1000 members)? By sub-sequences I mean runs like `0, 0` or `5, 5, 5`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: What is "at least"? The answers so far are sufficient for lists of a few thousand or so (unless the operation will be done repeatedly in some tight  loop, then even that will add up). For large lists they can be significantly beaten.

Answer (score 7):

Modifying the approach by @bbgodfrey one might also use [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html?q=Tally) to count all patterns:

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 1000]; (* some integers *)  

patternCount = Tally @ Split @ list (* returns a list of {{integer..},count} *)
```

Now we just take the ones that interest us (e.g. more than one integer):

```
patternCount2plus = Cases[ 
    patternCount, 
    { { Repeated[ _Integer, {2, Infinity} ] }, count_Integer }
]

(* { {{3,3}, 11}, {{4,4}, 8}, ... }*)
```

This might be sorted by the elements that are repeated and formatted more nicely:

```
patternCount2plusSorted = SortBy[ patternCount2plus, #[[1,1]]& ];

Grid[
    patternCount2plusSorted,
    Alignment -> Right,
    Background -> { None, { {LightBlue, White} } }, (* alternate rows *)
    Frame -> True
]
```

Giving something like this:

[image: Output]

Comment: Perhaps, your second line of code should be `patternCount = Tally@Split@list`, and your third `patternCount2plus = 
 Cases[patternCount, {{Repeated[_Integer, {2, Infinity}]}, 
   count_Integer}]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, of course, thank you. That happens when one copies like the monks in medieval times. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If the `List` is named `lst`, then

```
rept = Cases[Split[lst], z_ :> z /; Length[z] > 1]
```

finds all runs of repeated integers, and

```
Length[rept]
```

finds the number of them.  Applied to

```
lst = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4}
```

they give

```
(* {{3, 3}, {5, 5, 5}} *)
(* 2 *)
```

If only the number of repeated runs is desired, then

```
Count[Split[lst], z_ /; Length[z] > 1]
```

can be used.  For instance,

```
SeedRandom[5];
Table[Count[Split[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 10^i]], z_ /; Length[z] > 1], {i, 1, 6}]
(* {2, 9, 93, 890, 9063, 90270} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 1000];

Tally @ Cases[{_, __}] @ Split[list]
```

{{{5, 5}, 4}, {{0, 0}, 10}, {{7, 7}, 9}, {{6, 6}, 12}, {{3, 3},
14}, {{9, 9}, 9}, {{1, 1}, 12}, {{4, 4}, 10}, {{6, 6, 6},
2}, {{8, 8}, 6}, {{2, 2}, 8}, {{0, 0, 0}, 1}, {{9, 9, 9},
1}, {{8, 8, 8, 8}, 1}, {{7, 7, 7}, 1}}

Alternatively, we could use

```
Tally @ SequenceCases[list, {a_, a_ ..}]
```

but it's rather slow

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `SequenceSplit`, but it is quite slow compared to @eldo's proposals with `SequenceCases` and `Split`. This way, grabbing @eldo's list and `SequenceSplit` we get:

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 1000];

Tally@Cases[{a_, a_ ..}]@SequenceSplit[list, s : {a_, a_ ..} :> s]

(*{{{5, 5}, 4}, {{0, 0}, 10}, {{7, 7}, 9}, {{6, 6}, 12}, {{3, 3}, 14}, 
   {{9, 9}, 9}, {{1, 1}, 12}, {{4, 4}, 10}, {{6, 6, 6}, 2}, 
   {{8, 8}, 6}, {{2, 2}, 8}, {{0, 0, 0}, 1}, {{9, 9, 9}, 1}, 
   {{8, 8, 8, 8}, 1}, {{7, 7, 7}, 1}}*)
```

A slightly faster version can be built using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
CountConsecutive[lst_?VectorQ] := Tally[
    Part[
            Reap[
                Module[{temp = {}},
                    Do[
                        If[
                                And[
                                    Greater[i, 1],
                                    Equal[lst[[i]], Part[lst, i - 1]]
                                ],
                                AppendTo[temp, lst[[i]]],
                                If[
                                    Greater[Length @ temp, 0],
                                    AppendTo[temp, Part[lst, i - 1]];
                                    Sow[temp, "temp"];
                                    temp = {}
                                ];
                            ];
                    ,
                        {i, Length @ lst}
                    ];
                    If[Greater[Length @ temp, 0],
                        AppendTo[temp, lst[[-1]]];
                        Sow[temp, "temp"]
                    ];
                ],
                "temp"
            ],
            2, 1
        ]
   ];
```

On my turtle machine I get the following:

```
CountConsecutive[list] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.0047334, {{{5, 5}, 4}, {{0, 0}, 10}, {{7, 7}, 9}, {{6, 6}, 12}, {{3, 3}, 14}, 
             {{9, 9}, 9}, {{1, 1}, 12}, {{4, 4}, 10}, {{6, 6, 6}, 2}, {{8, 8}, 6}, 
             {{2, 2}, 8}, {{0, 0, 0}, 1}, {{9, 9, 9}, 1}, {{8, 8, 8, 8}, 1}, 
             {{7, 7, 7}, 1}}}*)
```

A slightly faster alternative is to define `AdjacentDuplicates` and use `Select`:

```
AdjacentDuplicates = Most@# === Rest@# && Length[#] > 1 &;

Tally@Select[AdjacentDuplicates]@Split[list] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.002888, {{{5, 5}, 4}, {{0, 0}, 10}, {{7, 7}, 9}, {{6, 6}, 12}, {{3, 3}, 14}, 
             {{9, 9}, 9}, {{1, 1}, 12}, {{4, 4}, 10}, {{6, 6, 6}, 2}, {{8, 8}, 6}, 
             {{2, 2}, 8}, {{0, 0, 0}, 1}, {{9, 9, 9}, 1}, {{8, 8, 8, 8}, 1}, 
             {{7, 7, 7}, 1}}}*)
```